# PHP - Websocket best status code for CloseEvent?

Tags: php, websocket, status

I have a PHP websocket server with (for example) a maximum amount of 1000 connected clients at the same time. So when there already 1000 connected clients and a new client tries to connect, I have to return a websocket CloseEvent status code specified by [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent#Status_codes).

Status code `1013 (Try Again Later)` looks fine to me but I am not sure about it. Also `1008 (Policy Violation)` could be an option I think.

Is there someone who can recommend which one I should use in this case?